# Setting ionicDatePicker/ionicTimePicker as a service causing so many problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've tried to set up ionic datepicker and ionic timepicker as a service but run into some serious problems during the way.

My implementation is as follows:

**In controller.js**

```
function BusinessAddAppointmentCtrl($scope, ionicDatePicker, ionicTimePicker, DatePickerService, TimePickerService) {

  // Booking time and date

  $scope.booking = {
    'date': DatePickerService.getDate(),
    'time': TimePickerService.getTime()
  } 

  // Ionic datepicker

  $scope.openDatePicker = function(val) {
    ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker(DatePickerService.datePickerObject);
  };

  // Ionic timepicker

  $scope.openTimePicker = function () {
    ionicTimePicker.openTimePicker(TimePickerService.timePickerObject);
  };
}
```

**DatePickerService in services.js**

```
 function DatePickerService() {


    this.getDate = function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var dd = date.getDate();
        var mm = date.getMonth()+1;

        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10){
            dd='0'+dd
        } 

        if(mm<10){
            mm='0'+mm
        } 

        var date = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

        return date;
    } 


    this.datePickerObject = {
        callback: function(val) { 

            // Mandatory

            console.log('Return value from the datepicker popup is : ' + val, new Date(val));

            // Set new date

            var selectedDate = new Date(val);
            var dd = selectedDate.getDate();
            var mm = selectedDate.getMonth()+1;
            var yyyy = selectedDate.getFullYear();

            if(dd<10){
                dd='0'+dd
            } 

            if(mm<10){
                mm='0'+mm
            } 

            var newDate = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
        },

        from: new Date(), //do not allow past dates
        inputDate: new Date(),
        closeOnSelect: false,
        templateType: 'popup',
        weeksList: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
    }
```

**TimePickerService in services.js**

```
 function TimePickerService() {


    this.getTime = function() {
        var now = new Date();
        now.setMinutes(Math.ceil(now.getMinutes() / 30) * 30);

        var h = now.getHours();
        var m = now.getMinutes();

        var time = h + ":" + ("00" + m).slice(-2);

        return time;
    } 


    this.getRoundedTime = function() {
      var d = new Date(); 
      var ratio = d.getMinutes() / 60;

      // Past 30 min mark, return epoch at +1 hours and 0 minutes

      if(ratio > 0.5){
          return (d.getHours() + 1) * 3600;
      }

      // Before 30 minute mark, return epoch at 0 minutes

      if(ratio < 0.5) {
           return d.getHours() * 3600;
      }

      // Right on the 30 minute mark, return epoch at 30 minutes

      return (d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800;
    } 


    var timePickerObject = {
        step: 15, //Optional

        callback: function (val) {

            if (typeof (val) === 'undefined') {
                console.log('Time not selected');
            } 
            else {
                var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);
                console.log('Selected epoch is : ', val, 'and the time is ', selectedTime.getUTCHours(), 'H :', selectedTime.getUTCMinutes(), 'M');
            }

            // Set new time

            var selectedTime = new Date(val * 1000);
            var h = selectedTime.getUTCHours()
            var m = selectedTime.getUTCMinutes()

            var newTime = h + ":" + ("00" + m).slice(-2);
        },

        inputTime: this.getRoundedTime(),
        format: 24
    };

 }
```

The issues I am now experiencing are as follows:

1. I am not sure how to set `$scope.booking.date` or `$scope.booking.time` anymore, once the user selects a new date or time from the widget. Maybe because I don't understand how to set the value from services.js.
2. In `timePickerObject`, I can't seem to get a correct value here `inputTime: this.getRoundedTime()`, i.e. if the time is 23:30, I get 11:13 in the dialog.
3. Whenever the user attempts to set the time, I get the following error message: `TypeError: r.mainObj.callback is not a function` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEsRd.jpg).

Comment: firstly, a service is an isolated 'class' that acts as a singleton, it should not have anything to do with UI/UX, it can have getters/setters in it. Secondly, what is `mainObj` which is not present in this and I suspect its not in this code, Thirdly, have you debugged it.

Comment: @t0mm13b ok, the reason I wanted it as a service is because I wanted to call it from different controllers? Is my reasoning wrong. The alternative would see me duplicating the same code within each controller. Here are the full details of the `mainObj` error: http://imgur.com/BPN7bXF

Comment: Please refrain from posting images showing errors of any kind, please amend your question to include those details. As to your reasoning, its wrong, you could use a directive that can be used in many controllers.

Comment: @t0mm13b thanks, do you have an example that you can show me that will work in my case? I just need some guidance